# Accessing data in Google storage for Apache Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I have about 30Gb worth of data in Cloud storage that I would like to query on using Apache Hive from a Dataproc cluster. What's the best strategy to access this data. Is the best approach to copy the data to my master via *gsutil* and access it from there, or can I access it in Cloud storage directly ? If the latter, how do I specify its location in the Spark CLI ? Can I specify

```
location 'gs://<bucketname>'
```

when I run

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE
```

?

Comment: I now realize that I can specify the location directly in Cloud storage using `location 'gs://<bucketname>'`. Nevertheless the first part of my question still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create an external table which points directly at the data in Cloud Storage. This should work with both hive and Spark SQL. In many cases, this is probably the best strategy.

Here is an example based on a public dataset in Cloud Storage.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE natality_csv (
  source_year BIGINT, year BIGINT, month BIGINT, day BIGINT, wday BIGINT, 
  state STRING, is_male BOOLEAN, child_race BIGINT, weight_pounds FLOAT, 
  plurality BIGINT, apgar_1min BIGINT, apgar_5min BIGINT, 
  mother_residence_state STRING, mother_race BIGINT, mother_age BIGINT, 
  gestation_weeks BIGINT, lmp STRING, mother_married BOOLEAN, 
  mother_birth_state STRING, cigarette_use BOOLEAN, cigarettes_per_day BIGINT, 
  alcohol_use BOOLEAN, drinks_per_week BIGINT, weight_gain_pounds BIGINT, 
  born_alive_alive BIGINT, born_alive_dead BIGINT, born_dead BIGINT, 
  ever_born BIGINT, father_race BIGINT, father_age BIGINT, 
  record_weight BIGINT 
) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LOCATION 'gs://public-datasets/natality/csv'
```

Admittedly, based on the comment to your question, I am not sure if I am missing another part of your question.